# how to verify if the payment is completed using paypal?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am getting back the IPN response from paypal. The payment_status is pending. How can I confirm, if the payment is completed?!

Edit #1
I am using sandbox as if now. So is is because of that, it is showing pending payment status?!

Edit #2
I am using this sandox now, which I dont know whether its beta or normal one. https://developer.paypal.com/us . Could any one tell me which version is this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive a new IPN notification when the payment changes it's status to complete.

**Edit #1:**

There are two sandboxes you can use. Normal and Beta. A few weeks back there were problems with IPN responses from the normal sandbox, so I tried using the beta sandbox and all IPN's returned successfully, and not pending.

**Edit #2:**

```
'API_ENDPOINT', 'https://api-3t.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/........'
'PAYPAL_URL', 'https://www.beta-sandbox.paypal.com.......
```

Comment: If that is the case, then do I have to run Cron job check the status?!

Comment: I am using this sandbox now, I dont know whether its beta or normal. Could anyone tell me about this .https://developer.paypal.com/us

Comment: PayPal sends IPN's directly to your server, so you can parse the request directly and act upon it. You can for example ignore the 'pending' payment_status, and just wait for failed, completed etc.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my novice knowledge, but that is where the confusion is, I dont know how to check the IPN again. Do I need to run a CRON job for that!? I am refreshing my page but it is still pending.

Comment: IPN = Instant Payment Notification = PayPal sends http request to url of your choice. 

I recommend that you scroll through the various docs at the paypal developer central.